# WebView blank page : How to fix it?

Tags: android, webview, chromium

I have a problem, and I spent too much time to resolve it without any solutions to fix it.
I want to open a link in a webview.
My logcat and my run tabs show me the website is correctly loaded but my webview is still blank.

this is my code

```
public class WebviewFragment extends AppCompatActivity {

    @BindView(R.id.webview)
    WebView webView;
    private String newString;
    private String key = "KEY";
    Activity activity;
    Context mContext;
    private ProgressDialog progDailog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_webview_fragment);

        activity = this;

        progDailog = ProgressDialog.show(activity, "Loading", "Please wait...", true);
        progDailog.setCancelable(false);
        webView = new WebView(this);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setCacheMode( 10 * 1024 * 1024 );
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAppCachePath(activity.getCacheDir().getPath());
       webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);

        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
            if (extras == null) {
                newString = null;
            } else {
                newString = extras.getString(key);
            }
        } else {
            newString = (String) savedInstanceState.getSerializable(key);
        }
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                progDailog.show();
                view.loadUrl(url);

                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, final String url) {
                progDailog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        webView.loadUrl(newString);
    }

}
```

newString is the good link.
no error in my "logcat" tab, and no error in my "run" tab.
But I cannot solve this problem.

If you have any suggestions, let me know.

Comment: try removing this line `view.loadUrl(url)`;

Comment: @VivekMishra still blank unfortunatly

Comment: `setLoadWithOverviewMode(true)` loads the WebView completely zoomed out. So this might be the issue

Comment: Show your activity_webview_fragment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You load the URL into the WebView that you never add to the screen:

```
webView = new WebView(this);
```

And you never show it in your layout.

If you have a `WebView` in your layout, you probably wanted to use it as

```
webView = findViewById(R.id.<something>);
```

Instead of

```
webView = new WebView(this);
```

Comment: of course! thanks a lot!! I'm using Butterknife for the first time (student), so the solution is a mix between your solution (the most useful) and @user3413619 solution with Butterknife.bind(this); thank you too

Answer (score 0):

Hey it seems like you are using Butterknife and forgot to call

```
Butterknife.bind(this);
```

As this call will bind Butterknife binding to webview.